# How to quickly join two strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, benchmarking

It's common to need to join strings, and in Ruby we have common ways of doing it: appending, concatenating and interpolating one into the other, or using the built-in `concat` method in String. (We have multiple ways of doing it for flexibility and to ease the transition from other languages to Ruby.)

Starting with:

```
'a ' << 'z'      # => "a z"
'a '.concat('z') # => "a z"
'a ' + 'z'       # => "a z"
"a #{'z'}"       # => "a z"
```

Assuming we don't want to change either string and that the strings won't be assigned to variables, what is the fastest way to join them, and does the fastest way change as the size of the "left" string grows?

For those who can't figure out why we'd post questions like this, it's to help educate and show the most efficient way to do a particular task. Newcomers to a language, Ruby in this case, often drag old ways of doing something with them, and inadvertently write code that runs more slowly than necessary. A simple change to their coding style can result in faster code.

Comment: I assume you have the benchmark results ready and will post shortly? :)

Comment: Let me help you with that https://coderwall.com/p/ac5j9g/or-concat-what-is-faster-for-appending-string-in-ruby

Comment: @DeepakMahakale `.concat` mutates the left string, though.

Comment: "Assuming we don't want to change either string" - but your first two examples do change the first string.

Comment: yes, In that case option 3 and 4 are the only one's left

Comment: The assumption is the strings are fixed, not being reused. I'll add that. `'a'.concat('b')` doesn't change the value of `'a'`. It'd only change if it was a variable. Got a better way to phrase it?

Comment: It is mutation with or without additional variable :) So the benchmark is biased. Mutation usually faster than copying ;). I'd separate the benchmark into mutable and immutable string concatenation.

Answer (score 12):

Starting with short strings:

```
z = 'z'
'a ' << z      # => "a z"
'a '.concat(z) # => "a z"
'a ' + z       # => "a z"
"a #{z}"       # => "a z"

require 'fruity'
compare do
  append      { 'a ' << z}
  concat      { 'a '.concat(z)}
  plus        { 'a ' + z}
  interpolate { "a #{z}" }
end

# >> Running each test 65536 times. Test will take about 2 seconds.
# >> interpolate is similar to append
# >> append is similar to plus
# >> plus is faster than concat by 2x ± 0.1
```

Increasing the "left" string to 11 characters:

```
require 'fruity'
compare do
  append      { 'abcdefghij ' << z}
  concat      { 'abcdefghij '.concat(z)}
  plus        { 'abcdefghij ' + z}
  interpolate { "abcdefghij #{z}" }
end

# >> Running each test 65536 times. Test will take about 2 seconds.
# >> interpolate is similar to append
# >> append is similar to plus
# >> plus is faster than concat by 2x ± 1.0
```

51 characters:

```
compare do
  append      { 'abcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghij ' << z}
  concat      { 'abcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghij '.concat(z)}
  plus        { 'abcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghij ' + z}
  interpolate { "abcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghij #{z}" }
end

# >> Running each test 32768 times. Test will take about 2 seconds.
# >> plus is faster than append by 2x ± 1.0
# >> append is similar to interpolate
# >> interpolate is similar to concat
```

101:

```
compare do
  append      { 'abcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghij ' << z}
  concat      { 'abcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghij '.concat(z)}
  plus        { 'abcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghij ' + z}
  interpolate { "abcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghij #{z}" }
end

# >> Running each test 32768 times. Test will take about 2 seconds.
# >> plus is faster than interpolate by 2x ± 0.1
# >> interpolate is similar to append
# >> append is similar to concat
```

501:

```
compare do
  append      { 'abcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghij ' << z}
  concat      { 'abcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghij '.concat(z)}
  plus        { 'abcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghij ' + z}
  interpolate { "abcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghij #{z}" }
end

# >> Running each test 16384 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> plus is faster than append by 2x ± 0.1
# >> append is similar to interpolate
# >> interpolate is similar to concat
```

Once the strings got past 50 characters `+` consistently outperformed the others.

In the comments there are mention of some of these mutating the string on the left. Here's what would happen if it was a variable on the left, not a literal string:

```
a = 'a'
z = 'z'

a << z # => "az"
a # => "az"

a = 'a'
a.concat(z) # => "az"
a # => "az"
```

compared to:

```
a + z # => "az"
a     # => "a"

"#{a} #{z}" # => "a z"
a           # => "a"
```

Note: The initial version of answer had a bad test using:

```
"a #{'z'}"
```

The problem with that is Ruby is smart enough to recognize that `'z'` is another literal and converts the string into:

```
"a z"
```

with the end result that the test would be unfairly faster than the others.

---

It's been a while and Ruby's smarter and faster. I added a couple additional tests:

```
puts "Running Ruby v%s" % RUBY_VERSION

require 'fruity'

z_ = 'z'
compare do
  append       { 'abcdefghij ' << 'z'      }
  concat       { 'abcdefghij '.concat('z') }
  plus         { 'abcdefghij ' + 'z'       }
  interpolate1 { "abcdefghij #{'z'}"       }
  interpolate2 { "abcdefghij #{z_}"        }
  adjacent     { 'abcdefghij' ' z'         }
end

# >> Running Ruby v2.7.0
# >> Running each test 65536 times. Test will take about 3 seconds.
# >> adjacent is similar to interpolate1
# >> interpolate1 is faster than interpolate2 by 2x ± 1.0
# >> interpolate2 is similar to append
# >> append is similar to concat
# >> concat is similar to plus
```

`interpolate1` and `adjacent` are basically the same as far as the interpreter is concerned and will be concatenated prior to running. `interpolate2` forces Ruby to do it at run-time so it's a little slower.

Comment: It's a wiki so if you know what you're doing and want to improve it feel free. If you don't know and you change it expect it to be rolled back.

Comment: Your `interpolate` is not real interpolate because `"z #{"z"}"` will be compiled into `"z z"`. To do real benchmark here you have to introduce additional variable `interpolate { z = 'z'; "a #{z}" }`

Comment: You may want to add `"a" "z" #=> "az"` to your benchmark. (Weird, eh?)

Comment: I added some more tests; the situation is the same as the previous comment, along with the last comments in the answer. Ruby will recognize that the two strings are adjacent and concatenate them together prior to running.